# how do i print a different element of a list per loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

im making a quiz program where the the user can add as many questions as they want to the quiz and they can take the quiz as well. i just dont know how to print the questions individually.

```
questionsList = [] 
rightAnswersList = []
choicesList = []
while True:
    option = int(input("Add questions or take the quiz? 1 or 2 respectively: "))
    if option == 1:
       # adds a question to questionsList and choices to choicesList and answers to rightAnswersList 
    elif option == 2:
       # prints question1 --> choices --> asks answer then it loops so question2 and its choices will now be printed
```

Comment: This is unclear what you are trying print, there are three arrays, also what have you tried in regards to printing the questions?

Comment: Have you already done the official Python tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but this fulfills the bare minimum of what your comments ask:

```
questionsList = [] 
rightAnswersList = []
choicesList = []
while True:
  option = int(input("Add questions or take the quiz? 1 or 2 respectively: "))
  if option == 1:
    questionsList.append(input("Enter question: "))
    choices = []
    while True:
      choice = input("Enter answer choice or enter 'q' to exit: ")
      if choice == "q":
        break
      choices.append(choice)
    choicesList.append(choices)
    rightAnswersList.append(input("Enter answer: "))
  elif option == 2:
    for i in range(len(questionsList)):
      print(questionsList[i])
      print("Choices:\n" + "\n".join(choicesList[i]))
      answer = input("Enter your answer: ")
      print("Your answer is: " + answer)
      print("Correct answer is: " + rightAnswersList[i])
```

You may need to add additional code to filter user input or check user answers.